# getting the black shadow bar at the bottom of the view in ios7

Tags: ios7, ios7.1

i am doing one application.In that i used the below code to stop the override the status bar in my view

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
{
    self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 20,self.window.frame.size.width-20,self.window.frame.size.height);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    } else
    {
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
        self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

But if i do this i am getting the black transparent bar at the bottom of the view in simulator.But in device i am getting black color.And it is correctly working in ios6,only problem i ios 7 like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in a demo with default navigation bar and found same black stuff coming. So made some changes and below is working one -

```
if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
} else
{
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,0,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height);
    self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
}
```

You could give it a ran and let me know if anything come's up.